# Painting a Node in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to keep tracking of the users movements by creating a trail of where they have gone. I have most aspects of the program figured out, but I'm stuck on how to keep user movements on the pane.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawLines extends Application {
  @Override 
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Text text = new Text(150, 150, ".");

    pane.getChildren().add(text);
    text.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {          
      switch (e.getCode()) {
        case DOWN: text.setY(text.getY() + 10); break;
        case UP:  text.setY(text.getY() - 10); break;
        case LEFT: text.setX(text.getX() - 10); break;
        case RIGHT: text.setX(text.getX() + 10); break;
        default: 
          if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(e.getText().charAt(0)))
            text.setText(e.getText());
      }
    });

    // Create a scene and place the pane in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Draw a Line!"); 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.show(); 

    text.requestFocus(); 
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. If you know the bounds (x width, y width), just compare the current location to the max and min of each and if they exceed the max, reset the current position to the max in the dimension the current position is about to go out of bounds.

Comment: Or just don't move them in the first place if it will take them out of bounds.

Comment: I guess I have got it wrong. Does the OP wants to keep a trace of the `Text` by tracing user movements or just want it to be within bounds of the Pane?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Maybe you are correct. The question is not very clear.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. @ItachiUchiha answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Text` and add it to the pane for every user movement. Just create a new method which takes care of this and call it for every user movement.

```
private void leaveTrail(Pane pane, Text text){
    Text newText = new Text(text.getText());
    pane.getChildren().add(newText);
    newText.setY(text.getY());
    newText.setX(text.getX());
}
```

A complete working example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawLines extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Text text = new Text(150, 150, ".");

        pane.getChildren().add(text);
        text.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case DOWN:
                    leaveTrail(pane, text);
                    text.setY(text.getY() + 10);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    leaveTrail(pane, text);
                    text.setY(text.getY() - 10);
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    leaveTrail(pane, text);
                    text.setX(text.getX() - 10);
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    leaveTrail(pane, text);
                    text.setX(text.getX() + 10);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(e.getText().charAt(0)))
                        text.setText(e.getText());
            }
        });

        // Create a scene and place the pane in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Draw a Line!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        text.requestFocus();
    }

    private void leaveTrail(Pane pane, Text text){
        Text newText = new Text(text.getText());
        pane.getChildren().add(newText);
        newText.setY(text.getY());
        newText.setX(text.getX());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A sample image

[image]